# Cant store images on selected folder - multer and express

Tags: node.js, multer

So I had it all working and for what ever reason after trying to build on it I can no longer get my application working. First and foremost I just want to be able to save my uploads to a folder again.

```
const saveToFolder = path.join(__dirname + "/../../" + "uploads");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, saveToFolder);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileName = req.file.originalname + ".jpg";
        cb(null, fileName);
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (
            file.mimetype == "image/png" ||
            file.mimetype == "image/jpg" ||
            file.mimetype == "image/jpeg"
        ) {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(null, false);
            return cb(new Error("Allowed only .png, .jpg, .jpeg"));
        }
    },
});

router.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file); //Returning undefined
});
```

My Frontend

```
submitUpload = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("filename", this.state.filename);
        formData.append("file", this.state.file);
        axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/upload",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
            data: formData,
        });
    };
```

My folder structure is

```
backend
     routes
         uploadImg route (where I handle my post)
frontend
folderToStoreIn
```

The req.file in my post request forever returns undefined. I've not idea what I've changed to stop it working and I can't understand how too revert it, it all looks fine

Thanks.

Comment: What value is this.state.file in your front end?

Comment: Thats it! I forgot the 0 index. Thank you

Comment: haha, no problem. We all miss stupid tiny things.